# Simulate keypress with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension to automate some tasks but I need a Chrome extension to do so.

I am currently setting the innerHTML of the textarea but this isn't triggering the word count, it's only if I type it triggers the word count

I have tried an array of solutions eg dispatching a keyboard event and using the Chrome extension API.

None of this is working for me.

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my issue. Do you also know a way to click enter?

Comment: Try clicking the submit or confirmation button.

Comment: @wOxxOm Apologies for not giving more information. For the send button, using .click() doesn't seem to be working, nor any events.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when `Enter` is pressed? Insert a new line of text? Submit your form? Something else? The reason I'm asking - if you want a new line, just insert `\r\n`. If it's submitting, programmatically trigger `form.submit()`, etc.